# Images being distored if width is smaller than container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get all of these different size images to remain undistorted. All the images look great except for the ones that have a smaller width than the container of 285px. I'm ok with the images being blurry because I know we are stretching them. I just want all of them to keep their aspect ratios. The ones that are not working are images #2, #3, and #4.

I can't use any JavaScript for this. It needs to be pure css.

http://jsfiddle.net/pp74fb7b/9/

```
.squaregallerywrap {
width:  285px; 
height: 285px;
}

.squaregallerywrap img {
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
max-height: 286px;
min-width: 286px;
display:block;
margin:auto;
position:relative;
-moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
-ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
-o-transform:translateX(-50%);
transform:translateX(-50%);
left:50%;
}

li {    
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: 0.4s all linear;
transition: 0.4s all linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid

just include:

```
<script src="js/imgLiquid-min.js"></script>
```

Call the function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".imgLiquidFill").imgLiquid();
});
```

Then add class="imgLiquidFill imgLiquid" to your image div container

```
<div class="squaregallerywrap imgLiquidFill imgLiquid" >
    <img src="/path/to/image" />
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use JavaScript in this project. I should have added that to the question.